# Join tables and only keep right ones, but keep amount of left ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two tables:

df1:

```
index   Address                                     type    amount   Epoch  ln of amount
0       0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833ad9B4999D62a7e3b70367  outflow 250000.0    1   12.429216
1       0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833ad9B4999D62a7e3b70367  outflow 250000.0    2   12.429216
2       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 250000.0    1   12.429216
3       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 33333.0     2   10.414303
4       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 33333.0     3   10.414303
```

and df2:

```
Index   Other Addresses                
0       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389
```

I want to create a new table that only contains the addresses (and all other respective columns) from df2, but the amount of rows needs to be the one on the left.

Basically, I am identifying which addresses from df2 exist in df1, and keep only those, with all of their information from other columns.

In my example, the resulting table would look like this:

```
index   Address                                     type    amount   Epoch  ln of amount
0       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 250000.0    1   12.429216
1       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 33333.0     2   10.414303
2       0xhj2gf34jhl23h23ljhn45b1836hfñlsxsdkjv389  outflow 33333.0     3   10.414303
```

Comment: Take a look at [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Comment: Just gives me a boolean for if the value  is in the entire table, but doesn't match rows individually.

Comment: [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing) is the very basic of `pandas` usage.

Comment: I think Henry means something like df3 = df1[df1['Address'].isin(df2['Other Addresses'])]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), as suggested in the comments:

```
df1[df1['Address'].isin(df2['Other Addresses])
```

---

Example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':['x','y','z']})
```

ie `df1` is:

```
   col1 col2
0     1    x
1     2    y
2     3    z
```

Create `df2` too:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1_other':[1,7]})
```

ie:

```
   col1
0     1
1     7
```

`df1[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1_other'])]` then becomes:

```
   col1 col2
0     1    x
```

Comment: Thanks, the piece I was missing was the outer df1[[]].